# Connecting to a VPN by Mac

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, connection

I'm trying to connect to VPN by my mac.

I tried both built-in and AnnyConnect clients to access, but the error is the same:

> Could not connect to server.  Please verify Internet connectivity and server address.

Even I tried to connect by windows using virtual machine (Parallels)..

But the server does ping with terminal.

I don't have any idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Window you can download VPN installers (be sure to choose 32 or 64 bit depending on your Operating system):
http://www.vpnauthority.com/setup.php

Or Windows also allows you can Use OpenVPN instructions (which is in the FAQ of the same site)

Macs have a similar setup procedure. Step by step instructions can be found at http://www.vpnauthority.com/faq.php?info_id=44#info08

I should also say that you will need a VPN Authority accounts.  There are other VPN providers that you can use, but they follow the same instructions (with different downloads).